# contentEditable superscript & subscript in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, contenteditable, superscript, subscript

The following DHTML formatting commands each work fine on a div with `contentEditable=true` in IE, Firefox and Chrome:

```
document.execCommand("superscript", false, null);
document.execCommand("subscript", false, null);
```

However, calling the command again to remove the formatting has no effect in Chrome.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Chrome?

Comment: Works for me for the simple cases I've tried. Could you post a test case?

Comment: Hm, there must be a conflict in my spaghetti-code implementation. [Test on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RWfe/) works.

Comment: I get the same thing when trying to remove superscript using the Redactor wysiwyg with a custom button. It does however work in a basic  contenteditable. A real head scratcher.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. For me, the problem was due to some "normalization" CSS altering `vertical-align: baseline` for sup and sub tags. Overriding that CSS and setting sub to `vertical-align: sub` and sup to `vertical-align: super` fixed it.

Comment: Excellent catch that saved me undoubtedly many hours of work trying to figure out wtf was wrong.